# Suponha que você quer juntar vários programadores em um só lugar

Tags: debate, meetup

No começo de Agosto/14 o SOpt vai estar na TDC em São Paulo. Provavelmente com um estande, brindes e tudo mais. Mas sabemos que muitos de vocês não vão participar da conferência e pensamos em organizar em encontro do site antes da conferência!

Não tem como ser algo grande nem elaborado... não é pra ser a StackConf Brasil (ps: Não existe StackConf). Apenas um dia para que as pessoas do SOpt possam se conhecer, trocar ideias e ter uma chance de interagir com a equipe do site.

Acredito que seja uma boa ideia, mas ao mesmo tempo não tenho ideia de como e onde organizar algo dessa forma. Conversei com o utluiz e o bfavaretto sobre o que a gente pode fazer, quanto ao formato e lugar, e chegamos a algumas ideias:

1. Um lugar de fácil acesso, preferencialmente público. Talvez a marquise do Ibirapuera (eu não sou de São Paulo, mas ambos concordaram que seria uma boa ideia). Estamos abertos a sugestões, ou oferecimento de espaço.
2. Nada técnico. Não faria sentido pedir pra todo mundo levar um laptop e ter discussões acaloradas sobre Java 8. A idéia é conhecer algumas das pessoas que interagimos todos os dias e jogar conversa fora.
3. Uma pequena abertura minha, sobre o site, a história por trás, quem fez, como funciona, etc. E mais quem quiser falar sobre experiências no site.
4. Um painel... um mini-meta... pra discutir alguns posts no site ao vivo e a cores.

Não queremos que seja formal, nem longo. Só uma tarde pra dar um rosto pro pessoal com quem a gente discute tanto, e talvez reclamar de como o site tá horrível e vai fechar.

Que tal? Alguém sugere alguma coisa? Discorda do formato?

Comment: Acho interessante a iniciativa. E so' para emendar um pouco: acredito que seria uma boa ideia ter sempre algo durante (dentro) da Campus Party Brasil...

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Não discordo. Tentamos algo esse ano, mas não deu. Fica pro ano que vem, né...

Comment: Outro lugar interessante em São Paulo é o [SESC Pompéia](http://www.sescsp.org.br/unidades/11_POMPEIA/#/content=facilidades). Tem espaços abertos e fechados, e *acho* que na choperia (que é bem grande) tem wi-fi. Só não sei se é tão acessível quanto o Ibirapuera. Aliás, o local mais acessível seria a Av. Paulista.

Comment: Acredito que você quis dizer `em organizar **um** encontro do site **depois** da conferência`, já que o TDC vai das 8h as 19h. Correto?

Comment: @Math A ideia é fazer o encontro no final de semana anterior à abertura da conferência.

Comment: @bfavaretto agora entendi! Valeu

Comment: Pena é eu estar em Portugal, se o SO PT pagar a minha viagem eu vou :D

Comment: A Campus Party Brasil é o lugar ideal, já fui em duas edições e lá há espaço de sobra. Da para enjoar da cara dos outros, hehe.

Comment: Que tristeza tudo ser em São Paulo. Catarinense se ferra. No mais, criaram já algum lugar para conversarmos sobre?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Se você acha que catarinense sofre por nunca ter nada aí, imagina ser do Espírito Santo ;D. E algum tempo atrás eu estava em Florianópolis, mas daquela vez tinha sido só eu...

Comment: Façam em Portugal e venham conhecer a Europa, afinal de contas devem ganhar bem ai ;)

Comment: @JorgeB "Ganhar bem"... Quem dera! No Brasil é muito comum o uso de `mysql_connect()` ainda, meu caro.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Mesmo agora com a evolução que o Brasil está a passar, não se ganha melhor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Mudança de planos

Não dei muita resposta por aqui justamente porque algumas mudanças aconteceram na organização da "vinda" da SE pro TDC.

Antes de mais nada, gostaria de agradecer ao @carlosrafaelgn pela oferta do espaço e ajuda na organização. A ideia é sensacional e pode vir a calhar com outros projetos do SO (pt ou en) no futuro, mas mais sobre isso quando necessário.
Por agora queria apenas agradecer e manter a oferta em aberto.

## Preparem os fraques e cartolas!

### <sup>Ou bermudas e camisetas, tanto faz</sup>

O período do TDC São Paulo vai servir como um lançamento público "oficial" do site (entre aspas porque vocês foram o lançamento oficial, e nada vai mudar isso nos nossos corações :D). Ou seja, vamos aproveitar a vinda do Joel pra cá pra explorar ao máximo possível, com a imprensa, empresas, famosos, artistas globais e tudo mais (boa parte disso é mentira).

Isso vai acontecer **provavelmente** na noite do dia 06/08 (quarta feira) em um bar próximo à Universidade Anhembi Morumbi, onde será o TDC. Vamos ter alguns convidados de empresas, talvez representantes de sites de notícias, outros programadores conhecidos convidados e, obviamente, vocês (artistas globais :D). Drinks por nossa conta!

A ideia é fazer um encontro informal, entre vocês, a gente e mais alguns convidados. Nada exagerado já que quinta feira é dia de labuta, e nada que vá ocupar o fim de semana de alguém.

A única coisa que eu preciso agora é saber **quantas pessoas planejam ir?**
Não vai ser uma festa fechada, não precisa dar nome nem nada, mas a maior parte do pessoal vai vir da nossa comunidade, e eu preciso saber o tamanho do lugar.

Então, se puderem deixar um comentário (ou votar em um comentário só, sei lá), eu posso ter um estimativa.

Comment: Podem votar nesse comentário se tiverem interesse em ir!

Comment: Gostaria de ir, mas não posso. Ministro aulas todas as noites e algumas tardes/manhãs. Mas vou ao TDC, e conversamos melhor lá! Pode ser? :)

Comment: Dia 06/08 é ótimo pra mim ;)

Comment: o grupo SE paga-me a viagem? ;)

Comment: @Gabe que horas deve começar o evento?

Comment: @Math A conferência termina às 19hrs. Ainda depende do lugar, mas como deve ser próximo à TDC, deve ser antes das 20h

Comment: @Gabe e até que horas acha que vai? (Sim, eu deveria ter perguntado tudo de uma vez só). É que como eu tenho que viajar para comparecer tenho que ver se não vou chegar depois de já ter acabado, rsrs.. Mas pela hora que começa acho que vai rolar sim, tanto que já dei meu +1 no comentário.

Comment: @Gabe, sondando, não estarei longe do local... Posso dar um pulo lá... **Qual o nome do bar? A partir de que horas?**

Answer (score 13):

Gostei muito da ideia e do formato!

Se vocês quiserem/acharem viável, existe o espaço do Colégio Bandeirantes / Faculdade BandTec.

Sou professor lá e organizo eventos. Nós temos uma infraestrutura bem legal, com espaços *abertos* e *fechados*, *salas* e *auditório*. Todas as salas/auditório têm wifi, datashow, microfone sem fio e ar condicionado. *Temos dezenas de notebooks à disposição dos participantes* (caso seja necessário no dia). É possível também fazer transmissões ao vivo de lá. **Não há custo algum para ninguém!!!**

Estamos acostumados a sediar eventos de comunidades Linux. Além disso, sediamos o Mozilla Tech Day em junho de 2013, o IteropMIX em 2012, e novamente, em novembro, sediaremos o InteropMIX 2014.

*É possível organizar o evento para o início de agosto/fim de julho, sem problema algum! Aliás, me predisponho a ajudar/organizar pessoalmente, caso seja desejável/necessário.*

Só não é possível realizar eventos aos domingos, pois a instituição está fechada :)

O local é de [fácil acesso (ver mapa)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/R.+Estela,+268+-+Vila+Mariana/@-23.5778371,-46.6434661,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x94ce59905bce8029:0x735d60acd4c4bbcd) praticamente do lado da **Estação Paraíso do Metrô**, que é próximo à **Paulista** e ao **Centro Cultural São Paulo**.

Nosso espaço comporta *bastante* gente tranquilamente, mas se for preciso, também é possível organizar o espaço para ficar aconchegante para poucas pessoas (de 10 a 100) participantes.

Existem diversos restaurantes e lanchonetes bem próximos a nós (no máximo dois quarteirões de distância) e três estacionamentos.

Para quem vier de fora, se precisar, existem três hotéis nas redondezas, sendo dois a um quarteirão do local.

Nosso espaço:

[image: Nosso espaço 1]
[image: Nosso espaço 2]

Comment: Dia 14 de agosto vai ser em uma quinta-feira, mas devido a trabalho acredito que muitos não iriam, mas em um sábado acredito que daria para juntar muitas pessoas. Poderia criar um canal no facebook para criar os eventos com @Math havia sugerido no inicio para poder organizar o evento por lá também com o pessoal da SO. A cada hora que passa esse post fica melhor.

Comment: A instituição está aberta aos sábados! Podemos utilizar o espaço, sem problemas! Se precisar de mais ajuda para organizar, também podemos ajudar :)

Comment: Está meio em cima, mas dá para organizar grandes coisas para esse encontro. E fazer virar o encontro. Incentivar novos programadores, apresentar a muitos deles o SO. E mostrar o mundo dos programadores brasileiros. Se a galera abraçar a ideia eu topo. Podiamos começar até ao invés de tratar como apenas um encontro, startup ou brainstorm fazer isso como uma espécie de feira, se duvidar sairia até palestra. Acho que se sair do papel vai ser algo interessante para todos. E algo para escrever na história.

Comment: Dá tranquilo para organizar. Se o pessoal topar, já começo o processo aqui dentro.

Comment: Puxa vida, queria tanto um encontro no domingo =/ Minhas aulas da pos voltam dia 01/09, e é de sexta a noite e sabado das 9h as 16h.. Será que não dá pra marcar o encontro sábado 26/07? rs... apesar de eu achar que tá muito em cima

Comment: @Math 26/07 dá para fazer (do nosso lado aqui). Precisa ver com o pessoal ;)

Comment: @Math apertado, mas acho que rola. O ideal mesmo era ter uma forma de levantar quem tem interesse em ir e se possível a localidade que cada um realmente está, pois eu mesmo devo ir de carro e dependendo se confirmasse direitinho dava para levar mais gente, pois se eu for vou sozinho no meu carro. Estou em Valinhos/SP (Perto de Campinas) e o ideal era fazer uma programação ou algo do tipo, para deixar mais organizado. Qualquer ideia é bem vinda.

Comment: @Math se for dia 26/06 teria que já deixar o pessoal ciente agora (por causa do pagamento) rs..

Comment: @SilenoBrito pagamento doq?

Comment: @Math salário meu amigo rs..., vai chegando perto do fim do mês, o dinheiro vai ficando escarço. Se ficar muito em cima da hora, pode ter gente quer ir, mas como não se preparou financeiramente pode acabar perdendo a oportunidade.

Comment: Existem vários estacionamentos próximos ao local, quem quiser ir de carro não terá problemas! @SilenoBrito acredito que você quis dizer *26/07* ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Isso mesmo 26/07, erro meu rs...

Comment: @SilenoBrito é vdd, é uma coisa a se considerar, mas considerando que a maioria das pessoas recebem no dia 5, não tem mt diferença dentre fazer dia 2/8 ou 26/7

Comment: @Math ah sim, do dia 02/08 para 26/07 concordo. É que eu estava pensando que seria mais próximo do dia 14/07 tipo 09/07. Mas realmente nesse caso não tem muita diferença mesmo.

Comment: @SilenoBrito dia 9/7 não é possível pois estará ocorrendo o TDC, e o SOPT "estará" lá, pelo menos o Gabe. E conforme o post dele a sugestão seria de fazer antes desse evento, por isso imaginei que ele ocorreria dia 2/8

Comment: @Math Todos serão muito bem vindos lá em ambas as datas (26/07 ou 02/08)! :)

Comment: @Math para mim acho que rola, tem que ver com o restante do pessoal, seria bom levar uma galera grande. Será que o moderador ou administrador tem como enviar um convite para os usuários (se existir a ferramente , se o administrador achar que é uma boa oportunidade e que vale a pena enviar essa notificação aos usuários) e não for contra a politica do site

Comment: Não tinha vista essa proposta ainda. Genial! Obrigado pela iniciativa!

Comment: @utluiz Às ordens! :) A proposta está 100% firme e de pé! Se a comunidade topar, já organizo tudo lá. Será uma honra!!! Se precisar, passo meu email ou outro contato (Skype, celular etc...) :D

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Nesse quesito é o Gabe quem "manda". Ele deve estar bem ocupado esses dias organizando a vinda do pessoal de fora, então vamos aguardar o pronunciamento dele, que não deve demorar.

Comment: @utluiz Sem problemas! Estou por aqui todos os dias ;)

Comment: Carlos, excelente sugestão! Agradeço muito a proposta e talvez nós possamos usá-la num futuro próximo, mas pro período da TDC as coisas mudaram um pouco. Vou escrever minhas resposta daqui a pouco.

Comment: @Gabe Sem problemas, fico no aguardo. Se quiser, podemos organizar tudo para dia 26/07 ou para 02/08. Dá tempo de sobra ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Se formos utilizar seu espaço, vai ser provavelmente mais pra frente (setembro ou outubro). Se você for ao encontro, podemos conversar melhor.

Answer (score 9):

Faz tempo que saí de São Paulo, mas na Vergueiro se não me engano, fica próximo à Paulista e tem uma mega biblioteca ([Centro Cultural](http://www.centrocultural.sp.gov.br/)) perto, com estacionamento, condução (tanto ônibus quanto metro).

Próximo, tem lugares para comer a preços mais acessíveis (com base em conhecimentos defasados de 10 anos atras) e é fácil de escoar para Sé e 25 de março (coloquei 25 de março só para deixar mais pessoas empolgadas), aclimação, Ibirapuera e etc.

Tem um shopping ali perto também.

[image: Centro Cultural São Paulo]

Comment: Gostei, [tem internet](http://www.centrocultural.sp.gov.br/CCSP_wifi.html), [tem espaço](http://www.centrocultural.sp.gov.br/GALERIA_fotos_areas_de_conviv%C3%AAncia.html) e [muita coisa perto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centro_Cultural_S%C3%A3o_Paulo). Só precisa confirmar a viabilidade com alguém de lá, para não ter surpresas na hora. Vai que tá fechado para manutenção ou algo assim.

Comment: Muito boa a opção. Os espaços são excelentes, e o acesso também.

Comment: Ótima sugestão. Tem muito espaço aberto lá, mesmo que esteja ocorrendo alguma coisa (tem umas aulas de capoeira e coisas do tipo), dá pra arranjarmos um lugar.

Comment: O local é otimo. Uma das saídas do metrô Vergueiro dá direto ai, e na região tem muito lugar pra comer, etc.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ibirapuera](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Ibirapuera+Park/@-23.5868065,-46.6571286,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xcb936109af9ce541): viável, mas pouco acessível

O Ibirapuera e um lugar legal porque é aberto e tem muito espaço. O único problema do meu ponto de vista é não ter um metrô por perto. Eu *acho* que isso facilitaria bastante o acesso.

## Avenida Paulista: acessível, mas movimentada

Concordo com o [comentário do @bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1619/suponha-que-voc%C3%AA-quer-juntar-v%C3%A1rios-programadores-em-um-s%C3%B3-lugar#comment4635_1619) de que a Av. Paulista é mais acessível. Deve ser por isso que sempre que as pessoas sempre marcam de se encontra lá.

O único problema é se houver algum evento lá no mesmo dia. Se tiver algum protesto do MST, marcha pela maconha ou jogo do Corinthians no mesmo dia poderíamos ficar no meio de um possível confronto com a polícia. Nada demais para quem vive na capital... :D

Vou propor algumas alternativas na Av. Paulista mesmo:

### [Vão do MASP](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Museum+of+Art+of+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+Assis+Chateaubriand/@-23.561518,-46.656009,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x94ce59ceb1eb771f:0xe904f6a669744da1)

Sempre usado para encontros. Tem muito espaço, porém nenhuma infraestrutura. Tem alguns lugares para sentar, mas acomodaria poucas pessoas. Alternativas seriam usar para uma conversa inicial, depois se dirigir a algum local mais reservado.

[image: MASP]

[image: Vão do MASP]

### [Bob's da Paulista](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.559737,-46.658265,3a,49.2y,3.84h,85.82t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sWcDXJ2WYgH-CIO_E5Ej7bQ!2e0)

Se não forem muitas pessoas, podemos simplesmente se reunir no Bob's. Tem uma ambiente grande no fundo da loja que dificilmente está cheio. Também tem um espaço aberto ao lado (que pode ser visto no [link do Street View](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.559737,-46.658265,3a,49.2y,3.84h,85.82t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sWcDXJ2WYgH-CIO_E5Ej7bQ!2e0)).

Pesquisando vi que já [foi usado para *meet ups*](http://www.nparty.com.br/2014/04/compareca-no-meetup-n-party-no-bobs-da.html). Além disso, o Bob's é famoso pelo seu Milk Shake.

[image: Fachada Bob's]

[image: Espaço Bob's]

## [Parque Siqueira Campos (Trianon)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parque_Trianon)

Se preferirem um pouco de natureza, a Paulista tem esta opção. O problema é que não tem assentos.

[image: Parque Trianon]

### [Livraria Cultura](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.558417,-46.659976,3a,75y,217.29h,89.84t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sUo7812lUt6zdGyC6UepcvA!2e0)

Outro local de encontro, se não forem muitas pessoas.  Como é possível ver no canto inferior direito da foto, há um espaço para sentar e converter.

A livraria fica dentro de uma galeria, com outras opções de locais. Veja no [Street View](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.558417,-46.659976,3a,75y,217.29h,89.84t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sUo7812lUt6zdGyC6UepcvA!2e0).

[image: Livraria Cultura]

### [Shopping Center 3](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.558583,-46.659616,3a,75y,36.23h,89.35t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sqQDiXsZPHneuWoxfHkaTNQ!2e0)

Tem uma praça de alimentação grande.

[image: Center 3]

[image: Praça de Alimentação]

## Conclusão

Tente selecionar algumas opções de locais que conheço pessoalmente.

Eles são viáveis, principalmente se não forem muitas pessoas.

**Seria interessante termos uma noção de quantas pessoas vão estar por lá. Pode colocar meu nome na lista!**

Comment: Vamos começar a levantar o número de participantes? Talvez através de algum programa externo, tipo enquete, seila. A proposito, pode contar comigo.

Comment: Eu esperava que as pessoas comentassem ou respondessem aqui, e isso daria uma ideia de quantas pessoas pretendem participar. Vamos ver como a discussão evolui durante a semana (já que o Gabe postou isso na sexta após o expediente), e se não fizer muito sucesso podemos buscar algum outro jeito de estimar o número de participantes.

Comment: A Av. Paulista faz todo o sentido. +1 pela questão transporte. (e um pouco de saudade do tempo que eu era da vizinhança :) )

Comment: @bfavaretto Talvez pudéssemos criar um evento no facebook ou algum ou site de fácil acesso. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Fazem uma vaquinha para os Portugueses participarem? :P

Comment: Podia ser um lugar que vende cerveja, né?

Comment: `Podia ser um lugar que vende cerveja, né?` heuhuehueuh.. que milk shake que nada né não? xD

Comment: Seria uma boa também usar para discutir projetos pessoas e procurar inclusive pessoas que queiram fazer algo no tempo vago, como uma parceria para ajudar a acabar aqueles programas que fazemos e paramos sempre na metade por desanimo ou falta de tempo.

Comment: @SilenoBrito excelente! Acho que essa é uma das grandes vantagens desse encontro, trocar experiencias e contatos profissionais.

Comment: @SilenoBrito Acho que *networking* não vai faltar. Só não pode ser o foco, senão transformamos numa *startup weekend* resumida. :D

Comment: @utluiz Eu sinceramente acho que não dele ser o foco principal, mas um dos focos. Com certeza já é na mente de algumas pessoas. E os interesses nesse tipo de encontro são os mais diversos mesmo. Concordo com você que já está implícito, mas acho interessante deixar isso explicito, tipo reservar um tempo para brainstorming, e não voltado para a parte comercial de abrir empresas e montar negocio rentável, como é o foco da startup, mas para fazer um projeto que é hobby e que precisa de pessoas que compartilhem o mesmo interesse. Reunir ideias e interesses, conectar mentes. Tipo algo mais... :D

Comment: Estou vendo que esse será apenas o primeiro de muitos encontros..

Comment: Essa praça de alimentação do Shopping 3 é bem barulhenta. Dentro da galeria da Livraria Cultura acho que seria melhor porque tem uns quiosques com várias opções.

Comment: Paulista Estou Dentro.