# Encontro SOpt 2 - A Volta Dos Que Não Foram

Tags: debate, meetup

No começo desse mês o SOpt esteve na TDC-SP, com um estande, brindes e muita conversa pra todo mundo que chegasse lá. Eu tive a chance de conhecer brevemente alguns de vocês e conversar mais tempo com outros. Foi uma experiência que achei muito interessante e que não pôde ser mais aprofundada por conta dos horários e obrigações normais de cada um. Isso é uma pena.

Algum tempo antes da TDC eu havia proposto um encontro do SOpt em São Paulo mas aquela ideia foi posta de lado com a organização do evento e nossa festa "oficial" de "lançamento" no Rhino Pub. Pois então, com a sensacional ajuda do [carlosrafaelgn](/u/7998), temos a faca e o queijo na mão para fazer um evento só nosso, do jeito que a gente quiser.

As propostas feitas [naquele post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1619/12) continuam valendo, assim como o local oferecido pelo carolsrafaelgn. Então preciso apenas da confirmação de vocês para escolher uma data.
Por motivos de força maior o encontro precisaria ocorrer até meados de Setembro e preferencialmente em um fim de semana.

Se houver interesse de vocês, começaríamos a organizar (e pedir mais camisetas e adesivos!) imediatamente para que tenhamos um dia só para conversarmos sobre o site e todas as maneiras que temos de ajudá-lo a crescer.

O que acham?

## Update

Precisamos organizar isso rápido, bem rápido. Se você **tem interesse** de ir, preciso saber qual o melhor dia para organizar, então aqui vai:

### <strike>Formulário para o encontro</strike> Evento cancelado

Gostaria que esse formulário fosse preenchido por vocês o mais rápido possível, para que tenhamos tempo de organizar as coisas.

Comment: Quanto a *"as maneiras que temos de ajudá-lo a crescer"*. Acredito que divulgar para colegas/alunos/professores seria a forma mais efetiva de fazer o site crescer (boca a boca / panfletos em murais de universidades) . Mas isso depende de um pouco de empenho pessoal de cada um.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Sim. Mas não queremos forçar nada disso. O SOpt só tende a crescer naturalmente, do jeito que todos os sites da SE crescem (Google :p). A ideia do encontro é mais poder promover um debate mais aberto e dinâmico sobre o projeto.

Comment: Gabe, só marcar quando e onde. Do dia 30 ao dia 9 estarei viajando, não coincidindo estarei lá com certeza.

Comment: Eu tenho interesse. Vai ter mais chope?

Comment: Vai ter suco de laranja? :b

Comment: @utluiz vai ter suco de laranja, mas ele vai parecer de limão e ter gosto de tamarindo. :D

Comment: Não marcando no dia 20/09 para mim está bom, pois tenho um casamento para ir.

Comment: Minha sugestão é aproveitar uma convenção tipo HighEdWeb '14 da vida e fazer o próximo SOPt (3?) aqui nos Estados Unidos, negociar uns descontos bons e trazer todo mundo pra vir fazer networking. ;)

Comment: Eu acho uma ótima! A escolha da data (e de outros assuntos que surgirem) talvez seja mais fácil se for feita no esquema de votações. Talvez se os próprios participantes forem sugerindo datas, os demais podem votar a favor daquelas que preferire/puderem... Seria um momento bacana pra usar a sugestão do @brasofilo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic#comment2718_264 :)

Comment: `Não posso no dia 20/09 porque vou no meu próprio casamento, mas dia 21 já estou disponível -- SuperNerd` :D (joke comment p/ quem não percebeu)

Comment: Quem me hospeda? :D

Comment: infelizmente eu sei que não irá ter como agradar nas datas a gregos e troianos, mas eu não irei poder na primeira semana de setembro ... se for em alguma outra dai já irá ter como...

Comment: @MarceloDiniz preenche o formulário lá. É o melhor jeito de decidir uma data

Comment: @Gabe já fiz isso também..

Comment: Se o Brasil não estivesse tão longe, até iria.

Comment: @Gabe existe alguma possibilidade do encontro ser em um domingo? Pois na planilha cada opção se refere tanto ao sábado quanto ao domingo. Outra coisa, sabe o horário que deverá ocorrer? Se disser aproximadamente já ajuda.

Comment: @Math Existe. A planilha tava discriminando por *fim de semana* mas acho que devia ter posto por dia... Quanto ao horário, não faço ideia.

Comment: Podemos fazer também uma versão Floripa do encontro em outra data? O pessoal além de aproveitar o encontro, aproveitaria Floripa! Se houver interesse posso conseguir o local tb!

Comment: @Gabe teria como realizar streaming ao vivo do evento? Não vou poder ir mas gostaria de assistir as palestras, acho que isso seria interessante também para a promoção da comunidade. Em relação a camisas e adesivos, se puderem enviar via correio pra mim eu agradeceria kk (posso informar meu endereço no chat :D)

Comment: @Orion Não sei se poderia ser algo mais avançado que um laptop e um hangout público... Não vai ser nada elaborado, nem tenho certeza de que vão haver palestras. Quanto aos brindes, pode ficar tranquilo. Mais gente vai receber presentes.

Comment: @Gabe, quanto as camisas e adesivos, existe mesmo a possibilidade de envio pelo correio? Eu queria muito participar mas, ir a SP esse ano para mim está bem complicado. Mas se existir uma edição aqui no sul, estou dentro!

Comment: Os Tugas sempre discriminados :P

Comment: Manda brindes para PT também @Gabe :)

Comment: @JorgeB. O pessoal de Portugal vai receber brindes também

Comment: @Caputo Não acho que deva ocorrer um encontro em outro lugar, pelo menos não tão cedo. Mas mais pessoas vão receber brindes, com certeza.

Comment: Ok @Gabe, Em uma outra oportunidade futura, quem sabe. Ano que vem tem o TDC Floripa novamente. Quanto aos brindes, seria bem legal :D

Comment: Dou minha morada @Gabe? ;)

Comment: Aqui em Portugal não há eventos do SOpt?

Comment: @Filipe em lugar nenhum há eventos do SOpt. Esse em São Paulo é absolutamente informal e, salvo mandar algumas camisetas e adesivos (que o pessoal de Portugal também vai receber mais pra frente), a SE não tem nenhuma participação. Se vocês quiserem organizar em encontro, só me avisar e talvez eu até baixe por aí ;)

Comment: @Gabe seria ótimo mas não sei o tamanho da comunidade aqui em PT, mas se aparecer mais pessoas interessadas, com certeza organizamos algo e você também será bem vindo :)

Comment: @Filipe podem contar comigo :)

Comment: @JorgeB. seria permitido aqui no meta criar um tópico sobre a questão? Assim seria possível levantar um número inicial de pessoas interessadas.

Comment: @Filipe Claro podes abrir, e ver se alguém alinha...

Comment: Eu estarei voltando a morar em São Paulo na próxima semana então, entre mudança, instalação e acomodação e o tempo do ócio, caso eu não me perca na cidade (não moro em SP há mais de 15 anos) quem sabe no final do mês não role alguma coisa.

Comment: Em que pé estamos com isso, @Gabe? Quantas pessoas demonstraram interesse em participar? Como está a votação em relação às datas?

Comment: Eu gostaria de ir, mas é longe de mais pra mim :( ... mas ainda posso ganhar a camisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SNAFU - Evento Cancelado

Parece haver alguma maldição antiga pairando sobre nosso encontro. Além do baixo número de pessoas interessadas, não é possível combinar a disponibilidade do local, a maioria das pessoas e a minha própria.

Eu gostaria muito de fazer o encontro. Como o @carlosrafaelgn falou, conversar com os poucos que conheci durante a TDC foi interessante e esclarecedor sobre as diferentes maneiras de ver e participar no site. Seria um prazer ter mais tempo para fazer isso novamente, com um número maior de pessoas.

Infelizmente, o dia escolhido por todos cai bem no meu último fim de semana antes de me mudar para os Estados Unidos. Não tenho como encaixar uma viagem à São Paulo. É uma pena.

Outras oportunidades podem aparecer, inclusive sem a minha presença, caso desejem organizar algo entre vocês mesmos. Não falta gente disposta ;)

Comment: Os moderadores podem ajudar a coordenar. Mas WTF é SNAFU?! E outra, se eu votar a favor desta resposta, quer dizer que gostei do cancelamento? :)

Comment: Situation Normal: All Fucked Up

Comment: Gabe, quantas pessoas preencheram o formulário? Só para saber se vale a pena tentarmos um encontro por conta própria. @bfavaretto fiquei com a mesma dúvida, que nem quando alguém posta algo no face informando alguma coisa ruim, não sei se curtir o post quer dizer que estou demonstrando apoio à pessoa ou que estou gostando de ver a desgraça alheia =X

Comment: @Math Foram 11 pessoas, 10 podendo ir nos dias 20-21

Comment: @Math Precisando, ainda podemos organizar lá na faculdade. Só não pode ser aos domingos, de resto, tudo ok!

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn se for no dia 13 eu posso, ou 27. De qlq forma só posso depois das 16h que é a hora que saio da pós, acho que meu horário não ajuda mt tb.. Cara, tava pensando, vc vai estar na escola amanhã as 16h? Eu podia dar uma passada aí pra gente trocar umas ideias. Ah sim, eu moro em tatuí, venho pra SP toda sexta a tarde/noite e volto sábado depois da aula.

Comment: @math lembrando que, como eu não vou, não precisa ser em Setembro ;-)

Comment: @Math Quer marcar para conversarmos sexta, dia 12? Minhas aulas começam às 19, assim, podemos conversar antes das 19 na sexta. Quanto ao sábado, dia 13 eu terei um compromisso pessoal, e não estarei na faculdade, mas dia 20 ou 27 estaria ok para realizar o encontro. Ou..... como o Gabe disse, pode ser em outubro/novembro/dezembro ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn na vdd eu não consigo chegar tão cedo em SP. Meu horário na empresa não é flexível e eu chego bem em cima da hora da aula, que é às 19:30. Tô achando que nossos horários não vão bater :/

Comment: @Math :( que outros dias você vem pra cá???

Comment: @Math entendi! Que tal sábado dia 27?

Comment: @Math hehehehe qualquer um dos dois! Mas... tendo em vista o cenário, acho que bater um papo, mesmo! ;)

Comment: @Math sábado, dia 20, também é possível dependendo do horário. Tenho um evento pela manhã, mas depois das 14 estaria ok... :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Que tal começarmos de novo a "convocação" em outro post, e tentarmos achar uma data mais pra frente onde consigamos juntar mais gente? Vou tirar a tag "destaque" daqui...

Comment: @Math Veja meu comentário acima para o Carlos.

Comment: @bfavaretto visto. Topo tentarmos o novo encontro sim.

Comment: @bfavaretto 100% de acordo! :D Se precisar, o Math tem meu email. O título do post podia incluir algo como "Encontro SOpt v3.0 ..." ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto Caso vocês tentem outro encontro, favor mencionar-me, para que não esqueça-me disso ^^.

Comment: @AllanRamos Quando organizarmos outro, vamos fazer um novo post aqui no meta, e colocá-lo como destaque para que apareça na coluna da direita do site (onde hoje está o FAQ da comunidade). Fique de olho lá!

Answer (score 4):

Sei que isso não é uma resposta, mas faço questão em reafirmar meu convite feito no outro post: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1640/7998

As portas estão super abertas e o @Gabe tem meu e-mail direto.

Meu encontro com o @Gabe no TDC foi espetacular, e foi uma pena que não pude ficar mais, devido a limitações do meu horário (professor...).

Ficaria muito feliz em receber a comunidade! :)